# EF Core composite foreign key and constraint

Tags: sql, entity-framework, foreign-keys

In my project I have noticed that I will be have a lot of dictionaries with the same structure:

- shortcut
- full name for tooltip

which will be used on many different business forms.

I started to thing that there is no sense to keep all of them in separate tables.

It is better to keep all of them in one table and provide an additional column (`DictionaryType`) which will separate them in the case of asking the database for data?

So one repository with such method

```
public class DictionaryEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public DictionaryType Type { get; set; }
}
```

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<DictionaryEntity> GetDictionaries(DictionaryType type)
{
    return await _dbContext.Dictionaries.Where(d => d.DictionaryType == type).ToArrayAsync();
}
```

If new dictionaries appear, I need to only extend `DictionaryType` and I don't need to worry about database changes or repo/service/controller changes.

For now it is nice and easy, but... I would like to configure foreign key in business entities in that way:

```
public class CarEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    
    public Guid ModelTypeId { get; set;}
    public DictionaryEntity ModelType { get; set;}
    
    public Guid PetrolTypeId { get; set;}
    public DictionaryEntity PetrolType { get; set;}
}
```

How to configure in EF Core, foreign key in that way where:

- `CarEntity.ModelTypeId` points to `DictionaryEntity.Id` and `DictionaryEntity.Type = DctionaryType.ModelType` ?
- `CarEntity.PetrolTypeId` points to `DictionaryEntity.Id` and `DictionaryEntity.Type = DctionaryType.PetrolType` ?

I read, that there is something like a composite foreign key, so I could do FK on `{ dict.Name, dict.Type }` but it demands from me to keep in `CarEntity` as many properties as composite foreign key have.

Is there a chance to do unique constraint across multiple tables ?

Something like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<CarEntity>()
        .HasCheckConstraint("CK_ModelType", "[ModelTypeId] IS NOT NULL AND [Document].[Type] = 'ModelType'", c => c.HasName("CK_ModelType_Dictionary"));
```

Comment: Did you find a solution by any chance?